# How do I solve this PHP version incompatibility on my host, and how to get that Kernel:class the right way?

Tags: php, laravel

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in
>   /home/capollos/public_html/canopyinteriors/index.php on line 50

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../../../canopy/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../canopy/bootstrap/app.php';
```

line 50 .. it has to do with the php version on my host cpanel.

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to at least PHP 5.5 to be able to use Class-name resolution with ::class

http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php

Check to see if your cPanel has a version changer.

Comment: Laravel 5.4 requires at least 5.6.4 - https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/composer.json#L18

Comment: Fair enough, he should probably be on 5.6/7.0 anyway for Laravel, but the support for class resolution via ::class was introduced in 5.5.x.

Comment: Thanks found the option to change to 7. @Zach